# regular expression to match certian special chars in middle

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to build java regular expression with following conditions:

1. The identifier may not start or end with a special character
2. sequences of multiple special characters are not permitted
3. permitted special characters are : colon,hyphen(minus),period(full stop) and underscore

i have done some analysis and built the regular expression :

`String regularexp="^[A-Za-z0-9](?:,/-/_.*?[^A-Za-z0-9]{2}).*?[A-Za-z0-9]$" ;`but somehow its not working .

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }

    }
```

can you please check where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to write if you focus on the parts that are *not* special characters. Then the string looks like this (in EBNF notation):

```
<word> (<special-char> <word>)*
```

- `<word>` is a sequence of **one** or more alphanumeric characters: `[A-Za-z0-9]+`.
  By requiring that a `<word>` is not empty, we guarantee that no
  sequences of more than one `<special-char>` can occur.
- And `<special-char>` is exactly one special character: `[-:._]`.
  I put `-` first so we don't need to escape it.

Putting it together:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-:._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OJQIrP/1)